# glmm (poisson or negative binomial) which explain the significance of each single level

Tags: mixed-model, negative-binomial-distribution, glmm, intercept

I'm using the function glmer.nb of the library MASS to analyse the effects of two fixed factors (temperature: 2 levels and salinity:3 levels) and nested random factor (Individual ID/room) on parasite infection (Which is my y)

[image]

I obtain this output which is saying me that salinity 19psu differ from the intercept (13psu) and temperature 23°C instead is not significant (does not differ from the intercept. But still I don't know whether salinity 19 psu is different from salinity 16 psu! And when I remove the intercept (+0) I obtain only that all are significant (I think only because they differ from 0). There is any other glmm function or library Which can I use to analyse the significance of each treatment compared to the other? Instead of having some of them included in the intercept and not understanding if they are truly significant?

Comment: You specified that room is nested within individual. Is that correct?

Answer (score 2):

A couple of notes:

- The estimated variances for your random effects are extremely small. This suggests that you do not need to include these terms as random effects.
- To get all pairwise differences between the different `salinity` levels, corrected also for multiple testing, you can either use the [**multcomp**](https://cran.r-project.org/package=multcomp) or [**emmeans**](https://cran.r-project.org/package=emmeans) packages in R.